# Collect all leaves of BST and make list of them

Tags: c, tree, binary-search-tree

I have simple BST with a node structure defined:

```
struct node
{
  int key_value;
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
};

typedef struct node * tree;
```

Now I'm supposed to create a 'leaves' function which will collect all the leaves' values and make the list of them, where list is a structure defined as follows

```
typedef struct l_node * pnode;

typedef struct
{
  int val;
  pnode next; 
} l_node;
```

The problem is I cannot find out how to pass an appropriate pointer to function leaves. I don't know whether it should be a pointer to pnode or simple pnode. What I've done o far is:

```
pnode leaves(tree tr)
{
   // create a pointer to empty list 
   // and pass it to another function maybe?
}

// this is an extra function to go through all leaves
void leaves_rec(tree tr, pnode * node) // pnode or pnode *?
{
  if(tr == NULL)
    return;
  if(tr->left == NULL && tr->right == NULL)
    {
       // ???
    }
  else
    {
      if(tr->left != NULL)
    leaves_rec(tr->left, node);
      if(tr->right != NULL)
    leaves_rec(tr->right, node);
    }
}
```

Comment: pnode pn = new l_node(); pn->val = 0; pn->next = NULL; leaves_rec(tr, pn); return pn;

Comment: Just advice: There is no real benefit in `typedef`ing a pointer, you will find it a problem in the future rather than a syntax improvement.

Comment: @bebbo It's the simpliest solution, but does it really solve the problem? I still can't find the way to update  `if(tr->left == NULL && tr->right == NULL)` case, because it'll require to change `pn` pointer somehow.

Comment: whether it should be pnode or pnode *, depends on your case. If you want to allocate memory before passing to leaves_rec, then do it as @bebbo has shown. If you want to allocate inside leaves_rec, then pass pnode * pn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this question is related  to learn and understand how trees and lists are working. For a real application you should consider using the std library which provides this all.

There is a given tree node structure. I'd rather name it leaf, and also add some data to it. Usually you are using a tree to manage some kind of data.
I'am also adding a pointer to the parent element - you'll need it if you plan to balance a tree somehow.
The tree is define by one root leaf.

```
struct leaf {
  int key_value;
  leaf * top;
  leaf * left;
  leaf * right;
  void * data;
};
```

Here is the list node

```
struct {
  node * next; 
  void * data;
} node;
```

Now a method is wanted to create a list from a given tree.

```
node * leaves(leaf * tree) {
    node * list = new node();
    list->next = NULL;
    list->data = NULL;

    if (tree != NULL)
        leaf2node(tree, list);
    return list;
}

node * leaf2node(leaf * l, node * n) {
    // go left first
    if (l->left != NULL)
        n = leaf2node(l->left, n); // list node n is updated

    // omit this if statement, to collect the whole tree
    if (l->left == NULL && l->right == NULL) {
        // create a new list node and copy the data pointer
        node * add = new node();
        add->data = l->data;
        add->next = NULL;

        // append the list node and make the new node current
        n->next = add;
        n = add;
    }

    // go right
    if (l->right != NULL)
        n = leaf2node(l->right, n);  // list node n is updated

    return n;
}
```

By changing where going left/right the order of the list is changed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this code seems to create the list from the whole tree. What if I want to create a list which consists of leaves only? By leaf I mean the node which right and left children is set to NULL.

Comment: then you need an additional if statement - I'll add it to the example